# Search option to only return articles about people on Wikipedia

Tags: search, wikipedia-api

I am trying to search for only people from Wikipedia and return them in some format (ideally using regex, but a simpler search is okay).

The following query is close, but doesn't allow me to include a specific search query and it appears to only included dead people (well I believe historic figures).

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=wikipedia&srprop=timestamp&eititle=Template:Persondata

The following query works although I can't seem to limit the results to people only.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Persondata&eilimit=100&format=xml&redirects

[API sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&list=iwbacklinks&format=json&iwblprefix=wikibooks&iwbltitle=Test&iwbllimit=10) |

Comment: You might be looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:PDATA or http://toolserver.org/~apper/pd/index.php

Comment: @Bergi You don't happen to know how toolserver works?  It appears to hold an entire replica of W(which is okay but probably not the best), but it would certainly be nice if the results where searchable similar to the ones above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [Wikidata APIs](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php) for semantic searches. Example search for P31 → 5 ("is a human"), using the Wikidata Query Service: http://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-todo/autolist.html?q=CLAIM%5B31%3A5%5D